Make template class method parameter type same as class template parameter (including void)
I would like to make a class method have a signature that matches the class template parameter, e.g., for a Class<T>, there's Class<T>::Method(T t) if T is not void, and Class<T>::Method() if T is void.
Compiling the attempted code below, if T is void, then both methods exist.  I'm not understanding why the same use of enable_if works for foo but not that version of print.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    template <typename U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<U>, void>
    print(void) { cout << "print void"  << endl; }

    template <typename U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<not(std::is_void_v<U>), void>
    print(U x) { cout << "print not void " << x << endl; }

    template <typename U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<not(std::is_void_v<U>), void>
    foo() {};

    // ... rest of class
};

int main()
{
    S<int> i;
    i.print(1);
    // i.print();  // is disabled

    S<void> v;
    v.print();
    v.print(2); // should be disabled but is not
    v.foo(); // same enable_if use disabled this method
}


v.foo<int>()

you are incorrect in thinking that the version of foo on the void version of  S doesn't exist.  The above code will run perfectly fine.
What you have shown is that the default template parameters pick a version that doesn't exist.
In the case of print, you provide default template parameters - but you also allow them to be both passed (ie, .print<double>(1)) explicitly, or be deduced (as in .print(2)).
In both of those cases, this result in a U type that is not T, hence not void.
There are at least 2 approaches.  You can block deduction (getting the foo style not-exist to work for print) and you can even block passing explicit parameters (preventing foo<int>() from being called).  Second, you can also use requires, which is cleaner but requires a newer version of C++.
To block deduction, you can use std::identity_t or you own hand-rolled equivalent:
template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<U>, void>
print() { std::cout << "print void"  << std::endl; }

template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<not(std::is_void_v<U>), void>
print(std::type_identity_t<U> x) { std::cout << "print not void " << x << std::endl; }

to block passing parameters explicitly, do this:
template <class..., class U = T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<U>, void>
print() { std::cout << "print void"  << std::endl; }

now any passed parameters get "swallowed up" by the class... and thrown away.
Doing both gives you a older-standard implementation that does most of what you want.
We can do better with requires however:
template <typename T>
struct S
{
  void print() requires (std::is_same_v<T,void>)
  { std::cout << "print void"  << std::endl; }

  template<class..., class U=T>
  void print(std::type_identity_t<U> x) requires (!std::is_same_v<T,void>)
  { std::cout << "print not void " << x << std::endl; }

  void foo() requires (!std::is_same_v<T, void>)
  {};
};

which sadly still requires some similar machinery for print.
As an alternative:
  void print(std::convertible_to<T> auto x) requires (!std::is_same_v<T,void>)
  { std::cout << "print not void " << static_cast<T>(x) << std::endl; }

using concepts to constrain the argument to be T compatible.
Live example.

Thanks!  I'm a little fuzzy on why std::identity_t blocks type deduction, but I can read up on that latter.
I'm having trouble applying the above method to creating a type alias for a std::function.  E.g,  I want a type S<T>::F  equivalent to std::function<int(void)>  if T is void, and std::function<int(T)> otherwise.  I have two definitions for the type alias using enable_if_t but keep getting redeclaration errors when instantiating either S<int> orS<void>.

@user1470475 That is a different question; ask it on the main feed, I or someone else can answer it.

One alternative is specialization of S<void> (or possibly S_Base<void> to not repeat common other code):
template <typename T>
struct S_Base
{
    void print(T x) { std::cout << "print not void " << x << std::endl; }
};

template <>
struct S_Base<void>
{
    void print() { std::cout << "print void"  << std::endl; }
    void foo() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct S : S_Base<T>
{
    // ... rest of class
};

If S_Base need access to S members, CRTP might be used.
